# platform independent document management system for private usage

Tags: privacy, documents, document-management

I want to switch my private red tape towards a document management system.
The system should be **platform independent**. The **data should stay in my hands**(no Google or M$).
 **OCR** and **search index** would be nice. 
Also i require some kind of encrypted backup.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software you might want to try [DocStorage](http://silvercoders.com/en/products/). There is OCR coming with it and you can search through your documents database basing on documents content.

I'm not sure if you can get it for free though...

You would probably need to obtain encrypted backups functionality with some other vendor.